# cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Vector2'

Tags: c++, struct

So I've been at this all day and maybe it could be that my eyes are so dead that I'm missing a simple list. I have vector3 and vector2 and thought I made it. Unsure now. It's been a long day

Error code below:
[ErroCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HATi.png)

Line 14 is

```
        pLocal.setViewAngles(Vector2(newAngle.x, newAngle.y));
```

But code comes from here:

```
#include "Modules.h"

Vector3 oldPunch = { 0.f, 0.f, 0.f };

void Modules::NoRecoil(LocalEntity pLocal) {

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)) {
        Vector3 viewAngles = pLocal.getViewAngles();
        Vector3 punchAngle = pLocal.getAimPunch();

        Vector3 newAngle = viewAngles + (oldPunch - punchAngle);

        newAngle.Normalize();
        pLocal.setViewAngles(Vector2(newAngle.x, newAngle.y));

        oldPunch = punchAngle;
    }
}
```

Then the actual call is:

```
struct Vector2 {
float x, y;

Vector2 operator-(Vector2 ape)
{
    return { x - ape.x, y - ape.y };
}

Vector2 operator+(Vector2 ape)
{
    return { x + ape.x, y + ape.y };
}

Vector2 operator*(float ape)
{
    return { x * ape, y * ape };
}

Vector2 operator/(float ape)
{
    return { x / ape, y / ape };
}

Vector2 operator/=(float ape)
{
    x /= ape;
    y /= ape;

    return *this;
}

Vector2 operator+=(Vector2 ape)
{
    return { x += ape.x, y += ape.y };
}

Vector2 operator-=(Vector2 ape)
{
    return { x -= ape.x, y -= ape.y };
}

void Normalize()
{
    if (x > 89.0f)
        x -= 180.f;

    if (x < -89.0f)
        x += 180.f;

    if (y > 180.f)
        y -= 360.f;

    if (y < -180.f)
        y += 360.f;
}

float Length2D()
{
    return sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));
}

float Dist2D(Vector2 ape)
{
    return (*this - ape).Length2D();
}
```

};

With the full source being:

```
#pragma once
#include <math.h>
#pragma warning( disable : 4244 )

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>
#define M_PI 3.14159265
#define RAD_TO_DEG(x) x * (180.f / M_PI)
#define DEG_TO_RAD(x) x * (M_PI / 180.f)

struct Matrix {
    float matrix[16];
};

struct Vector3 {
    float x, y, z;

    float distance(Vector3 vec)
    {
        return sqrt(
            pow(vec.x - x, 2) +
            pow(vec.y - y, 2)
        );
    }

    Vector3 operator-(Vector3 ape)
    {
        return { x - ape.x, y - ape.y, z - ape.z };
    }

    Vector3 operator+(Vector3 ape)
    {
        return { x + ape.x, y + ape.y, z + ape.z };
    }

    Vector3 operator*(float ape)
    {
        return { x * ape, y * ape, z * ape };
    }

    Vector3 operator/(float ape)
    {
        return { x / ape, y / ape, z / ape };
    }

    Vector3 operator/=(float ape)
    {
        x /= ape;
        y /= ape;
        z /= ape;

        return *this;
    }

    Vector3 operator+=(Vector3 ape)
    {
        return { x += ape.x, y += ape.y, z += ape.z };
    }

    Vector3 operator-=(Vector3 ape)
    {
        return { x -= ape.x, y -= ape.y, z -= ape.z };
    }

    void Normalize()
    {
        while (x > 89.0f)
            x -= 180.f;

        while (x < -89.0f)
            x += 180.f;

        while (y > 180.f)
            y -= 360.f;

        while (y < -180.f)
            y += 360.f;
    }

    float Length()
    {
        return sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z));
    }

    float Length2D()
    {
        return sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));
    }

    float DistTo(Vector3 ape)
    {
        return (*this - ape).Length();
    }

    float Dist2D(Vector3 ape)
    {
        return (*this - ape).Length2D();
    }

    struct Vector3 ScreenPosition(struct Matrix matrix) {
        struct Vector3 out;
        float _x = matrix.matrix[0] * x + matrix.matrix[1] * y + matrix.matrix[2] * z + matrix.matrix[3];
        float _y = matrix.matrix[4] * x + matrix.matrix[5] * y + matrix.matrix[6] * z + matrix.matrix[7];
        out.z = matrix.matrix[12] * x + matrix.matrix[13] * y + matrix.matrix[14] * z + matrix.matrix[15];

        _x *= 1.f / out.z;
        _y *= 1.f / out.z;

        int width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
        int height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

        out.x = width * .5f;
        out.y = height * .5f;

        out.x += 0.5f * _x * width + 0.5f;
        out.y -= 0.5f * _y * height + 0.5f;

        return out;
    }
};

struct Vector2 {
    float x, y;

    Vector2 operator-(Vector2 ape)
    {
        return { x - ape.x, y - ape.y };
    }

    Vector2 operator+(Vector2 ape)
    {
        return { x + ape.x, y + ape.y };
    }

    Vector2 operator*(float ape)
    {
        return { x * ape, y * ape };
    }

    Vector2 operator/(float ape)
    {
        return { x / ape, y / ape };
    }

    Vector2 operator/=(float ape)
    {
        x /= ape;
        y /= ape;

        return *this;
    }

    Vector2 operator+=(Vector2 ape)
    {
        return { x += ape.x, y += ape.y };
    }

    Vector2 operator-=(Vector2 ape)
    {
        return { x -= ape.x, y -= ape.y };
    }

    void Normalize()
    {
        if (x > 89.0f)
            x -= 180.f;

        if (x < -89.0f)
            x += 180.f;

        if (y > 180.f)
            y -= 360.f;

        if (y < -180.f)
            y += 360.f;
    }

    float Length2D()
    {
        return sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));
    }

    float Dist2D(Vector2 ape)
    {
        return (*this - ape).Length2D();
    }
};

struct AimContext {
    int FOV;
    int aSmoothAmount;

    int crosshairX = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 2;
    int crosshairY = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / 2;

    int entX = 0;
    int entY = 0;

    int closestX = 0;
    int closestY = 0;

    int aX = 0;
    int aY = 0;

    float entNewVisTime = 0;
    float entOldVisTime[100];
    int visCooldownTime[100];
};

//Player Stuff
struct colorRGB
{
    float r, g, b;
};

struct glowMode
{
    BYTE GeneralGlowMode, BorderGlowMode, BorderSize, TransparentLevel;
};

struct glowFade
{
    int a, b;
    float c, d, e, f;
};

struct Bone {
    BYTE thing[0xCC];
    float x;
    BYTE thing2[0xC];
    float y;
    BYTE thing3[0xC];
    float z;
};
```

I already have an initializer list for 2 floats in vector2, but I just can't solve this. Anyone is willing to point out my mistakes?

Comment: This is way more code than is needed to demonstrate the error. I don't see a constructor for `Vector2` that takes two arguments. I don't see any user defined constructors.

Comment: after some well needed rest I saw that I was missing quite a few things
very sorry everyone but I did solve it! thanks again !!

Answer (score 0):

Set build as 2020
add constructors for `Vector2`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).